# VLC Media player automatically create a blank duplicate when I open it

Tags: 12.04, vlc

When I open any video file with **VLC Media Player**, automatically another blank VLC Media player is opening.

And when I close the blank VLC player, both player turn off!

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution  :

Open **Vlc** -----> **Tools** ------> **Preferences** .

[image]

Check Allow only one instance .

Click Save , and check if your issue is solved.

Comment: I was going to give the same answer. That's it. +1

Comment: yes my friend , i think its the solution because it restrict one instance of vlc

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing two vlc windows one of two is blank and closing black one also clos your current window then use this;

Go To **Tools** -> **Preferences**->**Video** and uncheck **Accelerated video output(Overlay)**

[image]